# How can I create doc in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack

I am learning MongoDB with Youtube video(https://youtu.be/uX2G7Rt51WI?list=PLRQuJcU2aZG-aMedJxa7p7ylYmOn5iMlS) which I am following his code.

I don't think I made typo and I just think I missed some part but I don't know which part I missed.

I think he may create doc file somewhere in MongoDB, but I don't know where and how he made.

This is my code.

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb')
    .MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb')
    .Server;

app.engine('html', cons.swig);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

var mongoclient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017, {
    'native_parser': true
}));

var db = mongoclient.db('course');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    db.collection('hello_mongo_express')
        .findOne({}, function (req, res) {
            res.render('hello', doc);
        });
});

mongoclient.open(function (err, mongoclient) {
    if (err) throw err;
    app.listen(9000, function (req, res) {
        console.log('connecting 9000');
    });
});
```

Comment: I think he mentions at [this moment](https://youtu.be/uX2G7Rt51WI?list=PLRQuJcU2aZG-aMedJxa7p7ylYmOn5iMlS&t=242) that he's created the document in a previous exercise, most probably through the Mongo console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create a document. After the following line:

```
var db = mongoclient.db('course');
```

Add:

```
db.collection('hello_mongo_express').insert({ comment: 'This is cool'});
```